# Which SSL version does Apache HttpClient 3 use and can it be changed?

Tags: java, ssl, apache-commons-httpclient

If I try to connect to a https url with Apache Http client 3.1 like so..

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()
HttpMethod method = new GetMethod("https://federation/galaxy-class/enterprise/getSheildFrequencies")
int responseCode = httpClient.executeMethod(method)
```

which SSL version does it use in the handshake?

If it is SSLv2, is there any way to tell it to use a later version or TLS?

Answer (score 1):

At least Apache HTTP Client 4 uses the underlying JRE for SSL connections. So it's a matter of configuring the JRE (I would imagine the higher versions are enabled by default).

In an SSL handshake, the client presents it's highest supported version to the server by default. Then it's up to the server how high version it supports.

Try setting the "javax.net.debug" system property to value "ssl" so you can see the SSL handshake where the version is also displayed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Could you please give me a code example of how I can set this "javax.net.debug" system property?

Comment: never mind, I figured it out, for any other newbies out there, it was just System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");